# jQuery Plug-ins

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery plug-in which will show / hide a div in a very smooth & slide manners when I click on a link.

Do anyone have any idea or URL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[See demo here :)](http://jsbin.com/oqafi3)**

You can simply do like:

```
<style type="text/css">
#dv {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
</style>

<a href="#" id="link">Slide Div</a>
<div id="dv">Some Content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#link').click(function(){
    $('#dv').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need plugins for that; that's supported in jQuery out of the box:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').slideToggle('fast');
}
```